# How destroy associations in another schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, multi-tenant

I am using [apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) gem and my user (public schema) has many disputes (organization schema), when delete a user with disputes the associated disputes remain on db.

My user model have the correct association:

```
has_many :disputes, dependent: :destroy
```

Have any special setting that I need do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple, you should always call your request through the tenant url, never using the public (schema) url.

**Examples**

Tenant URL

```
DELETE http://bank.api.lvh.me:3000/users/1 # Bank is the name of tenant.
```

Public (schema) URL

```
DELETE http://api.lvh.me:3000/users/1 # Only delete the user, not with associations.
```